# Cron Job is giving status 127 for java code which is calling ruby script internally

Tags: ruby, unix, cron

I have cron scheduler for jar execution which is internally running ruby script, when I run the cron command on command line it works fine, and gives no error. But when I execute same command through cron then it is giving status code `127`. Considering the issue of environment variable(PATH) I tried to add `. ~/.bash_profile;` in cron command and run it again but it is giving me same status.

Below is the details of cron and ruby command:

Cron Command:

```
  30 5 * * * . ~/.bash_profile; java -jar /usr/car_price/bin/carUtils.jar
```

Ruby command called by jar:

```
ruby /usr/car_price/bin/apiclient.rb > /usr/car_price/rubyLog/2015-01-07_05:30:04_TPA.log
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does your Java code throw an error? (you can see cron script output in your root's `mail`). Do you use RVM or similar to manage Ruby executables? (executing `.bash_profile` is likely insufficient to create a workable environment.)

Comment: Java code is not throwing any error, but it is giving Exit_VALUE=127 for ruby call

Comment: Possible problem with $PATH or a typo Visit: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: Don't source your bash profile in cron.  Cron might not even run bash.  Instead, explicitly set your $PATH in your crontab.  On its own line at the top of your crontab, add e.g. `PATH=$PATH:/extra/paths:/go/here`.  The alternative would be to write a shell script, which would let you invoke the ruby script from outside your java code (which may independently solve your issue, since java may redefine the $PATH).

Comment: cron is giving below error:  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- hmac (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/ruby-hmac-0.4.0/lib/hmac-sha1.rb:1:in `<main>'